# YAML to be used between C++ and Perl

Tags: c++, perl, yaml-cpp

I'm attempting to parse a YAML file output from Perl's [`YAML::Tiny`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/YAML-Tiny/) using C++. As a C++ & YAML newbie, I'm using [HowToParseADocument](http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/wiki/HowToParseADocument) as a starting point.

The `monsters.yaml` file, if created by using `YAML::Tiny`, looks like:

```
---
name: Ogre
position: [0, 5, 0]
powers:
  - name: Club
    damage: 10
  - name: Fist
    damage: 8
---
name: Dragon
position: [1, 0, 10]
powers:
  - name: Fire Breath
    damage: 25
  - name: Claws
    damage: 15
---
name: Wizard
position: [5, -3, 0]
powers:
  - name: Acid Rain
    damage: 50
  - name: Staff
    damage: 3
```

I'm looking for help with morphing the example at [HowToParseADocument](http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/wiki/HowToParseADocument) to read in the modified YAML file with `---` as the separator for each entry.  I recopied the C++ main code below.

```
int main()
{
   std::ifstream fin("monsters.yaml");
   YAML::Parser parser(fin);
   YAML::Node doc;
   parser.GetNextDocument(doc);
   for(unsigned i=0;i<doc.size();i++) {
      Monster monster;
      doc[i] >> monster;
      std::cout << monster.name << "\n";
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The separator `---` splits the YAML file into several documents (as opposed to a single document consisting of a sequence, as in the example).

You could parse it like this:

```
int main()
{
   std::ifstream fin("monsters.yaml");
   YAML::Parser parser(fin);
   YAML::Node doc;
   while(parser.GetNextDocument(doc)) {
      Monster monster;
      doc >> monster;
      std::cout << monster.name << "\n";
   }

   return 0;
}
```